# Amazon web hosting URL not changing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Just hosted a website on amazon aws in a s3 bucket. When I move around in the website the URL doesn't change, even if the link redirect on a page with a different path.

I read around that it has something to do with iframes, even though I'm not sure what they are. 
Regardless, I'm just wondering whether it's possible with the aws s3 to make so that by moving around in the website, the URL gets updated as well.

For testing purposes, this is the [link to the website](http://www.paolo-caponeri.ga/), and to go to another part of the website, just scroll down and click on the website image.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: It's a multiple pages website, with the first folder index.html and a css folder, and another folder  with a html index and css folder that stores the other web page, shown in the image. I'm just using javascript and bootstrap. Since I don't thin I have a cloudfront setup, probably I don't have it. I have created a domain on a free domain website, just to make a easy free test-page. I've used freenom to create the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've manage to find out how to connect the web hosting s3 bucket to the freenom free domain provider.

1. The s3 bucket needs to have the same name as your domain + the "www". In my example my domain was paolo-caponeri.ga, the bucket needs to be www.paolo-caponeri.ga
2. Then in the freenom domains manager you need to go the name servers section, select the "Use default nameservers" and then press "save"
3. Finally you need to go to the freenom DNS manager and add a new CNAME record with "www" on the left and the full link to the s3 bucket provided in the amazon s3 properties on the right; in my case it was "www.paolo-caponeri.ga.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"

And that's it, after a while you should be able to connect to your website without having the URL being masked.
(thank you to Frederic Henri, who got me much closer to the answer!)

Answer (score 0):

NB: I have no experience with freenom so those are more advices than a proven solution.

It seems freenom is doing frame forwarding and you would need instead a "A" / "CNAME" referral.

Your site runs fine if you go to http://testpages.paolo.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ and as such bypass the freenom redirection.

A quick search on freenom seems it could be possible: https://my.freenom.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=4

Comment: So at the moment in order to connect the amazon s3 bucket to the domain I've put the s3 bucket endpoint in the URL forwarding setting of freenom. That works, but gives as the URL the s3 bucket endpoint, which is quite ugly. How do I make so that the URL displayed in the browser is equal to the domain name (www.paolo-caponeri.ga)?

Comment: did you read and follow instructions from https://my.freenom.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=4

Comment: Yes, it tells me to set default nameservers, which I did. And then to set up the DNS records (A, MX and CNAME record) which I'm assuming it is the way to link the s3 bucket to the domain. Not sure how I do that though. Should I get the A, MX and CNAME in some way from the amazon s3 bucket?